# Why does is this end of line (\\b) not recognised as word boundary in stringr/ICU and Perl

Tags: r, regex, pcre, stringr

Using `stringr` i tried to detect a `€` sign at the end of a string as follows:

```
str_detect("my text €", "€\\b") # FALSE
```

Why is this not working? It is working in the following cases:

```
str_detect("my text a", "a\\b") # TRUE - letter instead of €
grepl("€\\b", "2009in €") # TRUE - base R solution
```

But it also fails in *perl* mode:

```
grepl("€\\b", "2009in €", perl=TRUE) # FALSE
```

So what is wrong about the `€\\b`-regex? The regex `€$` is working in all cases...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use base R regex functions without `perl=TRUE`, [TRE regex flavor](http://laurikari.net/tre/) is used.

It appears that TRE word boundary:

- When used after a non-word character matches the end of string position, and
- When used before a non-word character matches the start of string position.

See the R tests:

```
> gsub("\\b\\)", "HERE", ") 2009in )")
[1] "HERE 2009in )"
> gsub("\\)\\b", "HERE", ") 2009in )")
[1] ") 2009in HERE"
>
```

This is not a common behavior of a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in PCRE and ICU regex flavors where a word boundary before a non-word character only matches when the character is preceded with a word char, excluding the start of string position (and when used after a non-word character requires a word character to appear right after the word boundary):

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>    - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
>    - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
>    - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Answer (score 3):

```
\b
```

is equivalent to

```
(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

which is to say it matches

- between a word char and a non-word char,
- between a word char and the start of the string, and
- between a word char and the end of the string.

`€` is a symbol, and symbols aren't word characters.

```
$ uniprops €
U+20AC <€> \N{EURO SIGN}
    \pS \p{Sc}
    All Any Assigned Common Zyyy Currency_Symbol Sc Currency_Symbols S Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase Print X_POSIX_Print Symbol Unicode
```

If your language supports look-behinds and look-aheads, you could use the following to find a boundary between a space and non-space (treating the start and end as a space).

```
(?:(?<!\S)(?=\S)|(?<=\S)(?!\S))
```

Comment: `(?:(?<!\s)(?=\s)|(?<=\s)(?!\s))` is not supported by TRE regex flavor as it does not support lookarounds. As for matching *a € sign at the end of a string*, the `$` will do.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, Thanks. I didn't want to completely remove the pattern since it could of use to others, but I rephrased the statement to account for the fact that it's not useful to the OP.

Comment: Yes, it will work with ICU (stringr functions) and `perl=TRUE` "powered" base R ones.

Comment: Ah, I see that it does match using a different engine, and I didn't explain that. That said, I did provide two important bits of information that are not in the other answer.