# R regex using stringr::str_detect and grepl don't seem to be matching "\\+" when it is surrounded by "\\b"

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm pretty new to regex and am trying to detect a word with the "+" symbol when surrounded by "\\b" in long strings of words but both stringr and grepl are giving me the wrong result.

This is the code that I have wrote:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect("coversyl +", "\\bcoversyl(plus| plus|\\+| \\+)\\b")
```

The output is FALSE which is wrong.

What would be the right way to do it?

Comment: Related to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174959/why-does-is-this-end-of-line-b-not-recognised-as-word-boundary-in-stringr-ic)

Comment: It is exactly this. The word boundary should not be used next to a non-word char if it must match when enclosed with non-word chars/start (end) of string. If you need unambiguous word boundaries use `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` lookarounds: `"(?<!\\w)coversyl(plus| plus|\\+| \\+)(?!\\w)"`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your expression is just fine, maybe missing an space,

```
\\bcoversyl\\b\\s(\\bplus\\b|\\+)
```

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/r9zkk9/1/)

If we might want more than one space, we would simply change `\\s` to `\\s+` and it might work:

```
\\bcoversyl\\b\\s+(\\bplus\\b|\\+)
```